# Understanding groupby() in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to understand *groupby()* operation. It is not enough to understand that grouby groups data because that is just first step, we do lot more with it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Animal': ['Falcon', 'Falcon', 'Parrot', 'Parrot'], 
                   'Max Speed': [380., 370., 24., 26.],  
                   'Class': ['Prey', 'Prey', 'Not Prey', 'Not Prey']}) 

In [7]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[7]: 
   Animal  Max Speed     Class
0  Falcon      380.0      Prey
1  Falcon      370.0      Prey
2  Parrot       24.0  Not Prey
3  Parrot       26.0  Not Prey
```

I do know groupby() does not operate on the original dataset, it works on a copy. The thing I am unable to understand is how code will look like after I do this:

```
df.groupby('Class')
```

Can I understand it visually?  I can understand original dataframe because I can **see** it is table and hence can imagine how the operations will go on it. So what happens when we do the above grouoby()? Does it create a new Series or 2 new Columns of which one is "Classs" and the other is a string containing all the other values?

I tried looking at offical docs user guide (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html) but that doesn't help in understanding how does grouby() look like after its operation

Comment: What is expected output from sample data? Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: If I create a minimal example here, post will become 4 times larger because I have to copy it from Kaggle. One reason I didn't do it

Comment: OK, so please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: I edited it and even made the code executable by anyone on their interpreter. Hope it is clear now

Comment: OK, answer was edited.

Comment: Also recommend this one to understand Group-By: https://github.com/jakevdp/PythonDataScienceHandbook/blob/8a34a4f653bdbdc01415a94dc20d4e9b97438965/notebooks/03.08-Aggregation-and-Grouping.ipynb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can check [this](https://re-thought.com/group-by/):

**GroupBy object**

> The groupby() function returns a GroupBy object but essentially describes how the rows of the original dataset have been split. The GroupBy object groups variable is a dictionary whose keys are the computed unique groups and corresponding values being the axis labels belonging to each group.
>
> If you simply run df.groupby('column_for_grouping') you will get a Python object that will look similar to . You may want to know how DataFrameGroupBy object looks internally. So lets print groups split by continent within our DataFrameGroupBy object by iterating through groups.

Comment: @Arnuld Use `birds.groupby('Animal')['Class']`

Comment: Your code is more readable, clear. It puts its intentions out very well. Groupby Animal and put Class in that group. Easy